# How to generate missing incremental row-values in a dataframe with Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns, seconds passed and a value. In the seconds passed row, the dataframe sometimes skips a second (data missing). I would like to fill in the missing seconds and intrapolate the missing value.

What I have tried so far is taking the first and last measurement of the dataframe, and arange a Numpy array containing all seconds passed from start to finish, converted this into a dataframe matching the first and tried to join or merge them.

The original df looks like this:

```
   seconds   value
0     1        5.560000
1     3        5.590000
2     4        5.620000
3     5        5.646667
4     7        5.653333
5     9        5.760000
```

I then create another dataframe, df2:

```
   seconds   value
0     1        NaN
1     2        NaN
2     3        NaN
3     4        NaN
4     5        NaN
5     6        NaN
6     7        NaN
7     8        NaN
8     9        NaN
```

The I tried merging them together, both ways around like so

```
df = df.merge(df2, how='left')
```

What I expect the output to be is

```
   seconds   value
0     1        5.560000
1     2        NaN
2     3        5.590000
3     4        5.620000
4     5        5.646667
5     6        NaN
6     7        5.653333
7     8        NaN
8     9        5.760000
```

but the actual output is either df or df2, unmerged. Is there a way to achieve the expected result, and am I on the right track or could this be done much more easily?

Comment: Try `df.merge(df2, how='outer')`. [Outer merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html): "use union of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL full outer join; sort keys lexicographically".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need the second df, use [`df.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df=df.set_index('seconds')
df=df.reindex(range(df.index.min(),df.index.max()+1)).reset_index()
```

---

If using the second df is necessary, you can use:

```
df=df.set_index('seconds').combine_first(df2.set_index('seconds')).reset_index()
```

---

```
   seconds     value
0        1  5.560000
1        2       NaN
2        3  5.590000
3        4  5.620000
4        5  5.646667
5        6       NaN
6        7  5.653333
7        8       NaN
8        9  5.760000
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using `update` and fix your problem

```
df1.set_index('seconds',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('seconds',inplace=True)
df2.update(df1)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Both answers work, accepted the first answer for eliminating the need to have an intermediary data frame.